# analog AbstractRoutingDataSource for Spring Data ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Does Spring Data ElasticSearch have something similar to `AbstractRoutingDataSource`? i.e. class(es) that route `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` requests to various target `RestHighLevelClient` based on lookup key.

That would be very handy for implementing multi-tenant solution using dedicated ES index per tenant as it will allow to keep `RestHighLevelClient` lookup logic out of the data access code.

Comment: do you want to have different indices in a single elasticsearch cluster or different clusters for each tenant?

Comment: The first option: different indices in a single elasticsearch cluster.

Comment: The RestTemplate is not bound to an index, it extractes the index from the arguments it gets or from the objects passed in.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I have the same question, but in my case I want to use different clusters for each tenant. Is there a way how can I make this happen? I am using Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.0